# Both Mozilla and Chrome are displaying half text

Tags: browser

I have a problem with the text display on my browsers;  My Mozilla and Chrome browsers display only the top 60% of some text.

[image: SU562911 example]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this persistent through restarts?

Comment: yes it is, restarts wont help

Comment: See this effect in any other apps, or only these two browsers?

Comment: Only in these 2 browsers. IE works fine..

Comment: I've read somewhere that the problem could be that i have too much helvetica fonts.. I searched and discovered i dont even have any Helvetica fonts. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Upload screenshots to any image host and post links in a comment.

Comment: http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/3762/wtftext.jpg

Here you can see 3 examples..

Comment: Oh i found out that it only displays for half when it is the 'Oswald' font.. Should i delete the font from my computer or what..?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it :) deleted the Oswald font from my computer and now it works fine :)

Comment: @Jeroen You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer.